# Python Logger Activated After Twilio?

Tags: python, logging, flask, twilio

I've created a standard barebones flask app which outputs the standard request lines like so:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:34] "GET /static/lib/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:34] "GET /static/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:34] "GET /static/lib/md5.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:34] "GET /static/lib/gmaps.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:34] "GET /static/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

But as soon as I initialize a `TwilioRestClient` instance from the [python Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install) driver, logging starts to look like this

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:55] "GET /static/lib/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:55] "GET /static/lib/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:55] "GET /static/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:55] "GET /static/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:55] "GET /static/lib/md5.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:55] "GET /static/lib/md5.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:55] "GET /static/lib/gmaps.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:55] "GET /static/lib/gmaps.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:55] "GET /static/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 13:23:55] "GET /static/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

The `INFO:werkzeug:` prefix leads me to believe werkzeug uses the default python logger but doesn't have it "enabled" but Twilio comes in and turns it on. I'm sure that's not exactly how it works, but you get the idea.

Do I have to manually disable python logger as soon as I initialize Twilio? How so? Can I leave it enabled for only Twilio?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Reproduce the problem

**twilio_test.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

app = Flask(__name__)

twilio_sid = 'TWILIO_SID'
twilio_auth_token = 'TWILIO_TOKEN'
origin_number = 'TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER'
recipient_number = 'YOUR_CELL_NUMBER'

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello!'

@app.route('/twilio/')
def hello_twilio():

    twilio_client = TwilioRestClient(twilio_sid, twilio_auth_token)

    twilio_msg = twilio_client.sms.messages.create(to=recipient_number, from_=origin_number, body='Twilio test script')

    return 'Hello Twilio!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

***output*** (notice the only request to /twilio/ is on the 4th line)

```
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 17:07:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 17:07:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 17:07:12] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 17:07:18] "GET /twilio/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 17:07:18] "GET /twilio/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 17:07:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 17:07:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 17:07:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 17:07:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 17:07:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2013 17:07:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: This is an interesting issue! Can you provide a reduced test case which reproduces the bug?

Comment: I wrote a sample app for you which reproduces the issue and added it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is extra calls to `logging.<x>` cause the duplicate errors. I was able to reproduce the issue with this gist (no Twilio):

https://gist.github.com/kevinburke/6477126

If you import `logging` at the top of your app Werkzeug won't have two log messages.

The relevant section of code in Werkzeug is here:

https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/_internal.py#L77

You want something like this at the top of your app to get exactly one Werkzeug/Flask debug logger:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: Yeah, looks like more of an issue with flask than Twilio.

Comment: Looks like Werkzeug is trying to be smart about logging, see the code I posted in the post.